# Django - How to annotate a single Django object

Tags: python, django

So Django has this cool feature where you can annotate a query set as in you can add attributes to each object in a query set. For example if I have a query set of users I can annotate it with number of followers which is another table with a foreign key reference to user. This can be done with the `QuerySet.annotate()` function. I was wondering if this is possible for a single Django object. I have a view function that gets user info, which given a unique user UUID I return the users info in the user table as well as the number of followers and followees. 1 way to do this is just query across all follower and followee table for the uuid and create a dictionary that gets returned. Or create a serializer with all the fields than annotate the single Django object like you can with a query set. Is it possible to do this?

views.py

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def get_user_info(request, user_uuid):
    is_current_user = user_uuid == str(request.user.uuid)

    # Return all user info including # of followers and followees
```

models.py

```
class User(AbstractDatesModel):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=USERNAME_MAX_LEN, unique=True, validators=[
        MinLengthValidator(USERNAME_MIN_LEN)])
    created = models.DateTimeField('Created at', auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField('Last updated at', auto_now=True, blank=True, null=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to=avatar_directory_path, blank=True, null=True)

class FollowUser(AbstractSimpleModel):
    follower = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='follower_id')
    followee = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='followee_id')
```

I tried this in `views2.py`, but the issue is that it doesn't properly just return the avatar url. `serializer.serialize` keeps `avatar` as an `ImageFieldFile` in the serialized user object.

views2.py

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def get_user_info(request, user_uuid):
    is_current_user = user_uuid == str(request.user.uuid)

    if is_current_user:
        user_object = request.user
    else:
        try:
            user_object = User.objects.get(uuid=user_uuid)
        except User.DoesNotExist as e:
            return Response(dict(error=str(e),
                                 user_message='User does not exist.'),
                            status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    user_dict = model_to_dict(user_object)
    user_dict['follower_count'] = len(FollowUser.objects.filter(followee=user_uuid))
    user_dict['followee_count'] = len(FollowUser.objects.filter(follower=user_uuid))
    user_dict['is_following'] = FollowUser.objects.filter(followee=user_uuid, follower=str(request.user.uuid)).exists()

    return Response(user_dict, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def get_user_info(request, user_uuid):
    query = User.objects.filter(pk=user_uuid)
    if query.exists():
        query_annotated = query.annotate(
            follower_count=Count('followee_id', distinct=True),
            followee_count=Count('follower_id', distinct=True),
            is_following=Count('followee_id', filter=Q(follower_id=str(request.user.uuid))))
    else:
        return Response(dict(error=str('User not found.'),
                             user_message='User not found.'),
                        status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
    serializer = FullUserSerializer(query_annotated[0])
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Maybe a solution? But `is_following` isn't returning the correct values in my tests.